# Installing feature in Azure startup task for Windows Server 2012

Tags: asp.net, iis, powershell, azure, windows-server-2012

I want to install the IP and Domain Restrictions feature in my Azure deployment, but I'm using os version 3 (Server 2012) which has depreciated ServerManageCmd, so the following code does not work:

**StartupTask.cmd**

```
@echo off

@echo Installing "IPv4 Address and Domain Restrictions" feature 
%windir%\System32\ServerManagerCmd.exe -install Web-IP-Security

@echo Unlocking configuration for "IPv4 Address and Domain Restrictions" feature 
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd.exe unlock config -section:system.webServer/security/ipSecurity
```

**ServiceDefinition.csdef partial**

```
<Startup>
      <Task commandLine="Startup\StartupTasks.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple" />
</Startup>
```

I believe I need to use powershell commands but I'm a little out of my depth here. Can anyone provide the 2012 equivalent of this code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For those playing at home, here's the answer!

```
@echo off

@echo Installing "IPv4 Address and Domain Restrictions" feature 
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -command "Install-WindowsFeature Web-IP-Security"

@echo Unlocking configuration for "IPv4 Address and Domain Restrictions" feature 
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd.exe unlock config -section:system.webServer/security/ipSecurity
```